# Casting variables with named list

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assign

In the R programming language I have a named list like the following one

```
list <- list(first='hello',second='bye')
```

I would like to cast the variables `first` and `second` with the values *hello*  and *bye* respectively. Obviously the real list is much longer that example one and I was wondering if there would be a better solution than using the function `assign` in a loop.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you use `assign` ? can you post your code + desired output

Comment: Why do you think you need that?

Comment: It is a bit obscure I know. The user has to supply some R expression in a very simple way and I need to parse stuff for the users formulas actually find objects to interact. so the users supplies _hello_ + _bye_ and need to cast that. Quite obscure explanation as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need `list2env`

```
mylist <- list(first = 'hello', second = 'bye')
ls()
## [1] "mylist"

list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
ls()
## [1] "first"  "mylist" "second"

second
## [1] "bye"
```